# How do I cancel a paste operation in Vim?

Tags: vim

I had rather a lot of text on my clipboard whenever I accidentally right clicked inside Putty (with Vim open), and Vim has initiated a paste operation which has been going for around ten minutes now.

I don't want to lose my unsaved work, is there a way to instruct Vim to stop pasting text?

Comment: Are you sure vim is locked up and not PuTTY?

Comment: Not certain to be honest, gonna rewire Putty's right-click function either way, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Not a solution now, but in the future i'd suggest you use something like `tmux`. In that case you could have quickly closed the putty window to stop it from sending more text from your clipboard up to the server. Then you could later reattach to that session and undo the paste operation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're in normal mode, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> aborts the current command in progress.  Then press <kbd>u</kbd> to undo anything that changed before you stopped it.

Comment: and what if you are not in normal mode e.g. you did 'i' to go into insert mode and you did cmd-v and  pasted?

Comment: Yes doesnt work for normal mode, which is when I have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old but the top answer is not right and I was clearly having a similar issue to OP.  (accidentally pasted like a million lines of json into vim)

Keep in mind this may not allow you to save your work (but you can probably salvage something from the .swp file)

All you need to do is open a new terminal window and enter `pkill vim` into the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Depending os your [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) configuration, there's chances that you have a swap file (backup) in `.nameOfTheOpenedFile.swp` (substitute *nameOfTheOpenedFile* with the name for your file).

To recover the file :

```
vim -r .nameOfTheOpenedFile.swp
```

Comment: I don't think that stops a paste though does it? note- i'm in insert mode, not sure if that makes a difference