# How do I cancel a vim paste in insert mode?

Tags: vim

I didn't see it coming and pasted a huge text corpus from the system clipboard into vim, and now the paste is progressing very slowly. As I said, there are solutions, but I didn't expect this.

Now that I am in insert mode, and vim is making progress in continuous paste attempts, how can I cancel this paste without killing vim?

There is an answer for normal mode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176964/how-do-i-cancel-a-paste-operation-in-vim), but I was in insert mode when I pasted from system clipboard (Cmd+v), and now I can neither switch tabs, change windows, or cancel the paste.

I'm using zsh, and default Vim (on MacOS- Big Sur)

Answer (score 2):

The usual suspects, `<Esc>`, `<C-]>`, and `<C-c>`, won't do anything until the input stream is finished so there is, AFAIK, nothing you can do.

Comment: To @romainl 's point, I don't think you can. I suggest you get used to switching just like you can't drive a car in only second gear. You might be able to do an insert mode macro, but it's probably easier to just hit ESC u